# MATCH function not working on Table headers for some reason

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

[image: Image showing the formulas. Working and Non-Working]
I am getting n N/A error when I am searching for a specific day in the header row. If you look to the right you can see the formula where I have searched for the position of 5 using MATCH and it works.

I have tried the following variations as well

```
MATCH(F7,Table2[[#Headers],[1]:[60]],-1)
MATCH(F7,Table2[[#Headers],[1]:[60]],1)
```

But these do not work.

On the right you can see that I have created a simple range of numbers from 1 to 9 and I have searched for the number 5 in it, it is working.

PS: I know I can just use the number "23" without using MATCH. But that is not the point, the column orders may be jumbled in some cases (product ID for example). The MATCH function shouldn't fail there.

Comment: Hello, does this help : https://exceljet.net/lessons/how-to-use-index-and-match-with-a-table :)

Comment: Table headers are strings, not numbers. Does it work using `=MATCH(TEXT(F7,"0"),Table2[[#Headers],[1]:[60]],0)`?

Comment: @Alex Richter. Yes that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being used as table-headers the days are not treated as numbers. Thus, you need to convert the expression you would like to match into text using `TEXT()` like this

```
=MATCH(TEXT(F7;"0"); Table2[#Headers]; 0)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works, you might want to replace the ";" with "," though.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `=index(area or table, 1 this is the row, match( field to match, area to search, 0 = exact match))`

Example source here https://exceljet.net/lessons/how-to-use-index-and-match-with-a-table

Hope this helps.